# When going back to the homepage (using React router), the api calls again (with redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, axios

Dear people reading this,

I hope somebody can help me. I already did some research, but I couldn't figure it out. I am new to React/Redux so thats why I need some help. This is the situation:

I have a React app and I am using React Routes, Redux and Axios to make api calls.

Everything works great, but when I switch from the main page to a different page and back, I see in my Redux Devtool that another api call is made. This is not what I want, it should only make an api call on first load (or when reloading the page). I thought with a SPA this was done automatically. I am fairly new to React and Redux, so any help is welcome. Is there any way to solve this?

This is my component file (CryptoContainer.js):

```
//CryptoContainer.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchCryptos } from '../redux'

function CryptoContainer({ cryptoData, fetchCryptos }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCryptos()
  }, [])
    return cryptoData.loading ? (<h2>Loading</h2>) : 
    cryptoData.error ? (<h2>{cryptoData.error}</h2>) : (
     <div>
       <h2>Crypto List</h2>
       <div>
          {cryptoData && cryptoData.users && cryptoData.users.map(user => 
            <div key={user.name}>
              <h2 >{user.name}</h2>
              <p>&euro; {user.current_price}</p>
            </div>)}
       </div>
     </div>
   )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      cryptoData: state.crypto
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      fetchCryptos: () => dispatch(fetchCryptos())
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CryptoContainer)
```

This is my redux Actions file:

```
//cryptoActions.js

import { FETCH_CRYPTOS_REQUEST, FETCH_CRYPTOS_SUCCES, FETCH_CRYPTOS_FAILURE } from './cryptoTypes'
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchCryptosRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_CRYPTOS_REQUEST
  }
}

export const fetchCryptosSucces = users => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_CRYPTOS_SUCCES,
    payload: users
  }
}

export const fetchCryptosFailure = error => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_CRYPTOS_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  }
}

let coinAmount = 10;

export const fetchCryptos = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchCryptosRequest)
    axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=${coinAmount}&page=1&sparkline=false`)
      .then(response => {
        const cryptos = response.data
        dispatch(fetchCryptosSucces(cryptos))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorMsg = error.message
        dispatch(fetchCryptosFailure(errorMsg))
      })
  }
}
```

This is my redux reducer file:

```
//cryptoReducer.js

import { FETCH_CRYPTOS_REQUEST, FETCH_CRYPTOS_SUCCES, FETCH_CRYPTOS_FAILURE } from "./cryptoTypes"

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  error: ''
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_CRYPTOS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }

    case FETCH_CRYPTOS_SUCCES:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: action.payload,
        error: ''
      }
    
    case FETCH_CRYPTOS_FAILURE:
      return {
        loading: false,
        users: [],
        error: action.payload
      }
      default: return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

I also have a cryptoTypes.js file where all the types are stored, but that's not important.

Is there any way I could achieve it so it only makes the api call on first load, and not when the (react) route changes?

I hope I gave enough information, any answer is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Greetings.

Comment: If your component is unmounted when you go to a different page. It should call the useEffect hook again. So the action will be called again for sure. I think if this is the problem you are saying it's the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting with:

```
const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  data: [],
  error: ''
}
```

It seems that you have a lot of `dispatch` events and this is causing `useEffect` to be called many times. I think the solution is to make `dispatch` possible.
I hope I helped, I'm Brazilian but I used the translator...